# Are badge progress numbers visible only to me or are they public?

Tags: discussion, badges

Can other users see *exact number* of things (edit, votes, review jobs), that I should do, to reach next badge? Or are they only able to *estimate* this, by looking at my badges ("guy has [*Strunk & White*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white), but not yet [*Copy Editor*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/copy-editor), so he edited *between 80 and 500 posts*" -- or something like that)?

Comment: It is all visible in your profile page, yes. E.g. you made [341 edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1469208/trejder?tab=activity&sort=revisions), though it doesn't say which of those were on your own posts which don't count towards the badges.

Comment: Thanks. Make that an answer, if you care for rep.

Comment: @nicael How question about "_view your own progress towards certain badges_" can be duplicate of question asking, if these numbers are public? I'm perfectly aware, how to view my own progress. I'm asking, if others can view the same (is it public)? For me, these are two different kinds of question.

Comment: @ChrisF Thank you for using your super-duper powers to close my question as a duplicate, which is not a duplicate. Have your read my above comment to _nicael_? This question **is not** a duplicate of mentioned one! It asks about something completely different...

Comment: Eh, saved by Laura. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean the "Badge Progress" box displayed in the */review* page?

> [image]

If that's what you mean then no worry, nobody else can see this box with your exact stats.

**However**, your actions are visible in your public profile page, e.g. [number of edits you made](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469208/trejder?tab=activity&sort=revisions). This number is "raw" and also contains edits to your own posts, which don't count towards the badges, but those who really want can construct queries in the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to get accurate progress.

For example, [you've made 188 edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7172/my-edits-sw-and-copy-editor?userid=1469208), which count towards the badges up until 2 days ago.